# How do I see how many people are in the guilds my bot is in?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to see how many users my bot could be interacted with (like how many users are in the guilds my bot is in)

```
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    if (!message.member.id === 'myid') return;

    message.channel.send(`Watching ${bot.users.size} users!`);
}
module.exports.config = {
    name: "users",
    aliases: []
  }
```

I also get this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'size' of undefined`
I know its silly but I just cant find it. Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you expect bot to look like? Where is the initializationcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `message.guild.memberCount` this will return total user count from which guild the command is executed from.